# Using MGF Technique to prove a theorem

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Use the MGF technique to prove the theorem:

> If X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>,...,X<sub>n</sub> are
> independent random variables where
> X<sub>*i*</sub>~Normal(µ<sub>i</sub>, σ<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>), then Y=Σ a<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub> follows a normal distribution with parameters µ = Σa<sub>i</sub>µ<sub>i</sub> and σ<sup>2</sup>= Σa<sub>i</sub>σ<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>

I do know how to use MGF for univariate case, but I am having a hard time understanding how to translate this to multivariate

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I'm done with setting up how the MGF will look like. Some sort of looking like E[exp{Yt}]. Although, I am not sure how I can input the value of Y as g(X) since there's a summation.

Comment: You can literally just plug in the definition of $Y$. That is, $E[\exp(tY)] = E\left[\exp\left(t \sum_i a_i X_i\right)\right]$. Then write the exponential as the product of exponentials.

Comment: Got it. I was able to figure and do that, but I don't know how to move forward and prove the theorem. It is basically reproductive property with only the constant a<sub>i</sub> being added in the equation, but still I'm not sure how I can come up to that.

Comment: @jrdp1803 Note that $E[\exp(a_i t X_i)]$ is the MGF of $X_i$ evaluated at $a_i t$. Look up the MGF of the normal distribution in question and plug in that value.

Comment: **Digest this first:** Let $X_1\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_1=1,\sigma_1=3)$ with MGF $M_1(t) = \exp(t+9t^2/2)$ and, independently,  $X_2\sim\mathsf{Norm}(2,4)$ with MGF $M_2(t) = \exp(2t,+16t^2/2).$ Then $X_1+X_2$ has MGF $M(t)=M_1(t)\times M_2(t) =\exp[(1+2)t+t^2(9+16)/2)]$ which is the MGF of $X_1+X_2=Y \sim\mathsf{Norm}(3, 5).$

Answer (score 0):

Statement $µ_y = \sum_i a_iµ_i$ is correct.
However, statement $σ_y^2= \sum_i a_iσ_i^2$ is wrong and should be
$σ_y^2= \sum_i a_i^2σ_i^2$ because $Var(aX) = a^2Var(X).$

> You do not show what you have tried to do with MGFs, but I'm guessing
> the incorrect statement about the variance of $Y$ may be causing you
> trouble. If you are still having difficulty with MGFs, please edit
> your question showing some of your work and where you're stuck, so that one of us can
> help with that. [To find the MGF of the sum of two independent random variables, take the product of the two MGFs. See my Comment.]

In the example below, independent random variables $X_i$ have
$E(X_1) = 50, Var(X_1) = 5^2 = 25;$ $E(X_2) = 60, Var(X_2) = 10^2 = 100;$
$E(X_3) = 60, Var(X_3) = 3^2 = 9.$

Also $Y = 2X_1 + 3X_2 + 4X_3.$ So $E(Y) = 520, Var(Y) = 1144.$ With a million
iterations of $Y,$ the sample mean $\bar Y \approx E(Y)$ and the sample variance $S_Y^2 \approx Var(Y).$

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = rnorm(10^6, 50, 5)   # mean=50, var=25
x2 = rnorm(10^6, 60, 10)  # mean+60, var=100
x3 = rnorm(10^6, 60, 3)   # mean=60, var=9
y = 2*x1 + 3*x2 + 4*x3
mean(y)
[1] 520.0287   # aprx 2(50)+3(60)+4(60) = 520
var(y)
[1]  1144.222  # aprx 4(25)+9(100)+16(9) = 1144
```

Because a linear combination of independent normal random variables is normal
with means and variances according to the formulas above, a histogram [blue] of the
million values of $Y$ is well approximated by the density function [orange] of
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_Y=520, \sigma_Y=\sqrt{1144}).$

```
hdr = "Simulated values of Y with Normal Density"
hist(y, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(y), sd(y)), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]